# CSS minimal margin

Tags: css, margin

I need to have a margin that is 7% wide, and at least 100px, how would i do this?

I tried

```
margin:7% 100px;
```

But it didn't work

Is there something like a min-margin?

Comment: margins are fixed. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no such thing as min-margin. You have to set a fixed margin, with a width in %, and a max-width.

Comment: I have a menu ul, it's min-width is 100 pixels, and width 7%. Next to it is a main div, with 93% width. I would like it to resize with the page, without overlapping the menu. My website is found at [CLICK](http://nefas.nl/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found an answer, this is the code that works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
if (GetWidth() < 1373) {
    console.log('changed < 1372');
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '100px';
}else{
    console.log('changed > 1372');
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '7%';
}

}, false);

function GetWidth()
 {
          var width = 0;
          if (self.innerHeight)
          {
                  width = self.innerWidth;
          }
          else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
          {
                  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
          }
          else if (document.body)
          {
                  width = document.body.clientWidth;
          }
          return width;
 }


</script>
```

It checks for every window resize, whenever you resize, it executes the function GetWidth. If the page width is lower than 1372, it changes the css of my div with ID 'main'.

Comment: you should consider using header, nav, section and other html5 tags later on (also dont forget to use shiv for older browsers). also you could give menu div a certain width, like 100px, and use margin: 0 auto; so the menu content was centered :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i've switched layouts so this code is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could assign a margin of 100px, and then override this using javascript (when a certain requirement is met), or you could use media queries

for example when width is >= 500px, change the styles so margin would be 7% instead of 100px

Comment: google for responsive web design :) there are like million questions/anwers on the web or stackoverflow itself answering your question, btw, you could aswell replace one class with other one

Comment: btw im not sure if you asked proper question, i think you might wanna check this link: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C9/ (first link that appeared in google #fixed-fluid)

Comment: Tried this code: `window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
if (GetWidth <= 1372) {
 document.getElementById('main').style.margin-left = '100px';
}else{
 document.getElementById('main').style.margin-left = '7%';
}

}, false);` Function GetWidth just returns the viewport width. But it still doesn't work..